# data identification from NNTP

Tags: networking, forensics

I've been on NNTP newsgroups and like to know how to identify the following NNTP header strings

That is, what is the meaning and where/how do I find those:

```
Injection-Info:logging-data="74569"
Message-ID: qjmbe4$28q9$1@adenine.netfront.net
X-Antivirus: AVG (VPS 190822-4, 22-08-2019)
Xref: news.netfront.net 24hoursupport.helpdesk:77925
X-Newsreader: Microsoft Windows Live Mail 16.4.3528.331
X-MimeOLE: Produced By Microsoft MimeOLE V16.4.3528.331
```

and where do I find more info on the above numbers/strings ?
what can those reveal ?
`74569`, `qjmbe4$28q9$1`, `190822-4`, `77925`, `16.4.3528.331`

I've googled but got a bunch of irrelevant results :(

Answer (score 2):

With the probable exception of `16.4.3528.331` (which appears to be a version number for Microsoft MimeOLE) and possibly `190822-4` (which appears to be based on the date), none of these numbers or strings have any *general-purpose* meaning.

By "general purpose meaning" I mean any meaning outside of the context of the message currently being processed or the specific programs that are processing it.

They are either generated (often semi-randomly) to create unique (or almost unique) identifiers with no actual meaning, **or** some kind of identifier or tracking code with a meaning which is relevant only to the program(s) that created them.   These strings are usually generated for logging purposes so that the trail of a particular message through different processes (queue IDs and process IDs, etc) and/or systems (Message-ID) can be tracked.

In short, they have no meaning.  Except for version numbers, they exist primarily to assist logfile analysis and auditing.  They are arbitrary identifiers.

Comment: OK, if I really clearly understand, this means that I can query the server
adenine.netfront.net / netfront.net that generated those string/numbers
qjmbe4$28q9$1 77925 and get some more info as a result
there seam not to be any interface for doing so.
so maybe there is some kind of obsur hack or something

thank's

Comment: it's extremely unlikely that there would be any service you could query as there is no need for one.  it's all effectively disposable information - some of it is logged first, but all of it is thrown away when the message has been processed/delivered.

Comment: @user2901196 If there was some issue with e.g. delivery of the message, an administrator could look at the mail server's log files and, by one of those IDs, possibly track down what happened.

Comment: Yes I know all of that. But what I'm trying to point out is that there must be out there on Internet some tools
(or hacks) to get that info -- from the outside --- WITHOUT having to SPAM the sysadmin all the time.
I'v been reading RFC 3977 977 5536 1036 5537 about NNTP and that info is -- indead -- logged in the remote
server and therefor -- accessible somehow. Of coarse not all NNTP servers log this info and some keep the logs
for a short period. But the sake of this discussion I'm this is irrelevant, since I query right away.
So email, twitter, or whatever mean of getting in touch

Comment: You might want to believe that there **must** be such a service you can query, or at least a protocol definition, but there isn't.  Reality beats belief.   And I'd bet that most sysadmins would just completely ignore any request to track an identifier unless the request was accompanied by a court order because it's a tedious chore to do that even when you want to for your own purposes (even assuming it hasn't already been auto-deleted by the log rotation cycle), let alone to satisfy the curiosity of some random stranger on the internet.

Comment: Many news (and mail) messages contain `Received:` and similar tracking headers you can examine.  But if you do so, you have to understand that any and all of them can be faked (they're just arbitrary text added to the message headers), and the **only** ones you can actually trust even to a small degree are the ones added by your own system.